# merging factor levels data.table way in R

Tags: r, data.table, factors

one of my variables called `type` looks like this:

```
$ type              : Factor w/ 4 levels "","a","e","u":
```

i would like to merge the empty factor level of the variable `type` with the factor level `"u"`

I have used the function `levels` to achieve this, but i do not feel so great about this solution.

```
levels(mydata$type) = list( u = "", a = "a", e = "e", u = "u")
```

Is there a more "data.table" like solution to merging levels of a factor variable in R?

Answer (score 0):

Your method:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(100)
mydata = data.table(x = runif(20),
type=factor(sample(c("","a","e","u"),20,replace=TRUE)))
levels(mydata$type) = list( u = "", a = "a", e = "e", u = "u")
table(mydata$type)

 u  a  e 
11  4  5 

str(mydata$type)
 Factor w/ 3 levels "u","a","e": 3 1 2 1 1 3 3 1 2 1 ...
```

I don't know if using `replace` is data.table like, but you essentially replace and drop the redundant factor:

```
set.seed(100)
mydata = data.table(x = runif(20),
type=factor(sample(c("","a","e","u"),20,replace=TRUE)))
mydata[,type :=droplevels(replace(type,type=="","u"))]

table(mydata$type)
 a  e  u 
 4  5 11

str(mydata$type)
 Factor w/ 3 levels "a","e","u": 2 3 1 3 3 2 2 3 1 3 ...
```